# script error in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, process, error-handling, browser

I am receiving and "stop running this script" error in Internet Explorer 9.0 , but in IE 8 and below is ok only I receive it in IE 9 can any one tell me what has been changed on IE 9 , I have already searched for this problem but most of  people trying to fix the issue using the patch provided by Microsoft .

I need to know why it is ok on IE 8 and it has problem on IE 9 ! or at least what I need to do to fix the problem in development side .

Thank you

Comment: Without showing your code, I suspect that this question will be closed  pretty fast. There could be a gazzilion of reasons why some javascript code behaves differently between IE8 and IE9. So code that would allow to reproduce the problem would be more than welcome.

Comment: the code is very much complicated , what I need to know is why it is not reproducible in IE 8 ! thanks for the comment .

Comment: I am afraid that in this case you will have to narrow it down. At its current state, this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem My self , there is a patch for IE 9 that you can install it will fix the problem

you can download it from here :
 http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/5/595D11B8-A0FD-4EA0-BF0D-F113258FC28A/MicrosoftFixit50403.msi

Comment: Can you please tell us what the problem was, and what the patch accomplishes?

Comment: problem was the 'Stop Script Error' that IE 9 shows when there is a time-consuming process. with this patch there is no more alert. if you need more information please read this article , http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260#appliesto